# Change variable when button is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a unity project where when the user presses a certain button a stat modifier will increase, how would I get this to work using C#? this is the current code but I feel like this is entirely in the wrong direction

```
public class logicBook
{

    public void Equip(Character c)
    {
        c.logic.AddModifier(10);
    }
    public int logic;
    logic = 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to C# and Unity so help would be really apricated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe by button you meant key so if you want to implement that you need first to have your class inherit from `Monobehaviour` so that you can use your script as a component of a gameobject.
then you should have an Update function (it is a function that gets called every frame) and rihgt there you can check the input

```
public class logicBook : MonoBehaviour{
    public void Equip(Character c){
        // do some cool stuff here
    }
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(/* Key that triggers this */){
       Equip(/* Argument here */); 
   }
}
```

If you want to have a button in game that triggers this function create a canvas UI in your scene and create a button object as a child of your canvas and then add the function to the button onClick component.